# PDFKit not working with parameters in GET call

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, pdfkit

My PDFKit on windows works fine with urls like : items/1 I can easily append .pdf at the end of this url like items/1.pdf and a PDF file is created.

But it does not work when I try to pass a parameter in the link which changes the url to : items/my_custom_action?item_id=1

Basically I am creating a printable HTML page in the second case and I want to convert into PDF using pdfkit.

I am using Rails 3.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a post form to pass params, this works fine for me.